# How to Show in Php if there is no value on database table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
<?php 
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT id FROM sample WHERE  ID = (SELECT MAX(id)  FROM sample)");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    foreach ($result as $row2) {
        $auto1 = $row2['id'];

            if ($auto1 ===' ') {
                echo "There is no ID!";
            } else {
                echo $auto1; 
            }

    }
?>
```

it shows the maximum id if there is value on database but when i'm deleting all data to try if i get the result of "There is no id on ID!" it doesn't show .. help me pls

Comment: Maybe you can try [`rowCount()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)?

Comment: uhmmm i am using the MAX() because i am creating a generated ID base on my autoincrement.. my problem is when there is no data on database.. it will give a value of 1.  i use max because if the user create another form .. it will get the max value of auto increment and add 1.  and it will save to the column of Autogenerated ID like "002" ..

Comment: Are you saying you want your error message to show up when there are no rows returned from your DB query?

Comment: yes.. a created error message. like echo "There is no value"

Comment: thx for the reminder.. i just finish my lunch and  read the answer below :D  thx :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code as it currently is won't hit your error message when zero rows are returned.  The line where you would get this info is:

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

The `fetchAll()` method will return FALSE if no rows are returned, so just check that value and display the error messages accordingly.

```
<?php 
    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT id FROM sample WHERE  ID = (SELECT MAX(id)  FROM sample)");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();


    if($!result){
        echo "No rows found..!";
    } else { 
        foreach ($result as $row2) {
            $auto1 = $row2['id'];

            if ($auto1 ===' ') {
                echo "There is no ID!";
            } else {
                echo $auto1; 
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: wow dude thx you save me :D and thanks for giving me the idea how fetchall() works  :D